# Input button - Onclick Color Changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I have the following HTML Code for a Specific Calendar Purpose. It should perform the following function.

1) First the user will select the Gender
2) The User shall select only one date
3) The selected date should be in Red Color

```js
function focusMe(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<table border="3" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" align="center"><b>First Visit Calendar</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" align="center"><i>Select your Gender</i>
      <select>
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" align="center"><i>Select your Date</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Sun</td>
    <td align="center">Mon</td>
    <td align="center">Tue</td>
    <td align="center">Wed</td>
    <td align="center">Thu</td>
    <td align="center">Fri</td>
    <td align="center">Sat</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="2">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="3">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="4">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="5">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="6">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="7">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="8">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="9">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="10">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="11">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="12">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="13">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="14">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="16">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="17">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="18">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="19">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="20">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="21">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="22">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="23" onclick="focusMe()" id="demo">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="24">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="25">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="26">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="27">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="28">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="29">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="30">
    </td>
    <td align="center" onclick="focusMe(this);">
      <input type="button" value="31">
    </td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What issue you are having and what you have achieved till now ?

Comment: I am able to make the selected button to turn Red, but even if I click on Multiple selections everything gets red.

At a time only one cell should be red colored.

Comment: Your JavaScript has no conditions to check. Have you tried to write anything?

Comment: No... I have no idea to try out the condition, so seeking your help..!

Comment: Downvoted because question is not seeking for any suggestion. Its clearly asking for code.

Answer (score 3):

Updated snippet for following condition:

> He/She will select the Date and only one date selection should be
>   possible

It can be done with some logic. Consider following logic:

```js
function reset(){
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0, length = td.length; i < length; i++) {
        td[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    }
}

function focusMe(el) {
    //removing previous selection
    reset();
    switch (document.getElementById('gender').value) {
        case 'Male':
            if (el.firstChild.value == 3 || el.firstChild.value == 5)
                el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            else
                el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            break;
        case 'Female':
            if (el.firstChild.value == 5)
                el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            else
                el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=3 CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=3> 
    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><B>First Visit Calendar</B></TD> 
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><I>Select your Gender</I><select id="gender"><option value="Male">Male</option><option value="Female">Female</option></select></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><I>Select your Date</I></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center>Sun</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Mon</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Tue</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Wed</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Thu</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Fri</TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center>Sat</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="1"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="2"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="3"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="4"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="5"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="6"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="7"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="8"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="9"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="10"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="11"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="12"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="13"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="14"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="15"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="16"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="17"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="18"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="19"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="20"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="21"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="22"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="23" onclick="focusMe()" id="demo"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="24"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="25"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="26"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="27"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="28"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="29"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="30"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center onclick="focusMe(this);"><input type="button" value="31"></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>
    <TD ALIGN=center></TD>

    </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

or

[**See Jsfiddle in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/gb2m36jp/3/)

Comment: Updated demo for `He/She will select the Date and only one date selection should be possible` condition, where user can choose only one date.

Comment: But Still, it is not working as per the condition...!! But the conditions given in the JS is correct.

Comment: Yes @GokulRavikumar I believe from here you can show your efforts. Or i can help you with this.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in a condition..! If a date is selected then the 3r,4th and 5th Days are not turning up Green automatically.

Comment: I believe you don't want to do anything by yourself. Here is no one can code for you.

Comment: Nope..! I am just getting to know a solution for a query..! I am almost to complete it...!

Comment: I can understand your condition `If a date is selected then the 3r,4th and 5th Days are not turning up Green automatically` you need to tween into logic. Like when select dropdown change then recheck all value.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly hold the previous selection and change its style on next selection

```
var previous=null;
function focusMe(el) {
  if(previous!=null){
    previous.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  previous=el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost arrived at the solution with slight modifications. There can be some reduced code than this and you can try it out too.

```js
function reset() {
      var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
      for (var i = 0, length = td.length; i < length; i++) {
          td[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      }
  }

  function focusMe(value) {
      reset();
      var text = "";
      var x = value;
      var j = parseInt(x) + 2;
      var k = parseInt(x) + 4; 
      var l = parseInt(x) + 5;
      var m = parseInt(x) + 7;
      var gen = document.getElementById('gender').value;
      if (gen == 'Male'){            
              text += "You can Visit us from " + j + " to " + k + "<br>";
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      }
      else{
              text += "You can Visit us from " + l + " to " + m + "<br>";
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      }

  }
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=3 CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=3> 
<TR>
<TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><B>First Visit Calendar</B></TD> 
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><I>Select your Gender</I>
    <select id="gender">
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD COLSPAN="7" ALIGN=center><I>Select your Date</I></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center>Sun</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Mon</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Tue</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Wed</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Thu</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Fri</TD>
<TD ALIGN=center>Sat</TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="1" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="2" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="3" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="4" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="5" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="6" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="7" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="8" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="9" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="10" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="11" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="12" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="13" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="14" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="15" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="16" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="17" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="18" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="19" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="20" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="21" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="22"></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="23" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="24" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="25" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="26" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="27" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="28" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="29" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
</TR>
<TR> 
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="30" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';"><input type="button" value="31" onclick="focusMe(this.value)"></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>
<TD ALIGN=center></TD>

</TR>
</TABLE>
<p id="demo"></p>
```